# UITableView, UISwipeActionsConfiguration, UIContextualAction - The pullView is not in a view hierarchy. This is a UIKit bug

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I have a UITableView with swipe action that when swiping: A) displays a blank/empty area where the swipe action button should display; and B) the following line is logged to the debug console in Xcode:

> [Assert] The pullView is not in a view hierarchy. This is a UIKit bug.

As of today, zero Google results exist for searching on the title of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the culprit was the following

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if !editing {
        rowSelectionState.removeAll()
        loadData()
    }
    refreshView()
}
```

Specifically, the `refreshView()` call, which contains a `tableView.reloadData()` call, needs to be inside of the `if !editing { ... }` block.  If not, when a swipe action is initiated, the swipe action appears to call `setEditMode(true, ...)`, thus calling `tableView.reloadData()` which messes with the `UISwipeActionsConfiguration`'s ability to be properly displayed.

Thus the above should look like this:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if !editing {
        rowSelectionState.removeAll()
        loadData()
        refreshView()
    }
}
```